# apply zsh themes manually

Tags: zsh, freebsd, oh-my-zsh, grml

I'm on freebsd (TrueOS, to be exact) and want to change my ZSH theme. ZSH was installed as binary package. I cloned the commonly known oh-my-zsh git repo, to gain themes, but want to stay with grml zsh config, which I downloaded from grml.org and placed into `/usr/local/etc/zsh`.

I'm sourcing `/usr/local/etc/zsh/zshrc` from my `~/.zshrc`, and now I want to use a theme from `~/.oh-my-zsh` (`agnoster`, to be exact, powerline and powerline-fonts are installed and working). But I have no idea ho to do this.

Please, how can I do this? I don't want to use OMZ. Just want to 'import' the theme(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the theme this can be rather tedious. Since they can depend on OMZ.

But luckily the [theme](https://github.com/agnoster/agnoster-zsh-theme) you mentioned doesn't seem to be depending on any other code.

Just download the the theme from the [Github page](https://github.com/agnoster/agnoster-zsh-theme), save it under `.zsh/themes`, and add

```
source ~/.zsh/themes/agnoster.zsh-theme
```

to your `.zshrc` and it should work (As long as there is no conflict).